# Iniciar sesión en una pagina web con python

Tags: python, login, python-requests, scraping

estoy haciendo un programa para automatizar algunas cosas en una web de citas [http://latinamericancupid.com/] pero tengo algunos problemas al iniciar sesion.

```
from requests import Session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
from codecs import open
def lgn():
        headers = {
             "Referer": "https://www.latinamericancupid.com",
             "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"
        }
        url = "https://www.latinamericancupid.com"
        login_data = {
             "email":"mail",
             "password":"password"
        }       
        password ="password"
        with Session() as c:
            c.get(url)
            html = c.post(login, data=login_data, headers=headers)
        html = html.content.decode()
        with open("prueba.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            f.write(html)
```

Este es el codigo, como se daran cuenta guarda el html que recibe en respuesta en un archivo, pero al abrirlo me pide que inicie sesion (osea que la autentificacion no funcionó)
[image: Login]

Pienso que quiza ocupe algo mas en el en la parte de `login_data`, el `form data` se ve algo asi. [image: login form]

Como puedo hacer para iniciar sesion en esta pagina?

Comment: No debería ser `c.post(url...` en lugar de `c.post(login...`?

Comment: @loki No, en '''login''' esta la url de el panel de login

Comment: tu código claramente dice que login es la función.

Comment: @loki Oh, aqui le cambie el nombre, pero en el codigo real se llama main

Answer (score 1):

En mi caso me pasó algo similar al utilizar request; decidí cambiarme a selenium por que al parecer el servidor detectaba que era un bot y me negaba el acceso o cerraba la sesión.

Los modulos a instalar son:
pip install selenium

[Y descarga el webdriver para tu versión de firefox](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options


    username = "tu correo de latin cupid"
    password = "contraseña"


    #SET WEBDRIVER
    options = Options()
    options.binary_location = r'Ruta del exe de Firefox' # Regularmente está en "AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'Ruta del WebDiver que descargaste \geckodriver.exe', options=options)


    # Abrimos la página con get del driver
    driver.get("https://www.latinamericancupid.com/en/auth/login")
    

    #Busca el id del correo y lo pone desde la variable
    driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="form-login-email").send_keys(username)
    # Busca e inserta el password
    driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="form-login-password").send_keys(password)

    # click login button
    Boton_login = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/form/button")
    Boton_login.click()
```